# Show NSTimeInterval continously

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

new to the iOS SDK and Objective-C and just have a quick question regarding the NSTimeInterval.

I have a really simple game, and I want to show for how long the game have been played (so that I can save away a best time).

Now, of course if I set the label's text with something like this:

```
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", -elapsedTime];
```

The text of the label will be how long time it will have passed since the game started, which is 0 seconds.

In what way can I have the elapsedTime object "running in the background" so that the player can se for how long he/she have played at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look as the NSTimer class to schedule a timer for a preset time and update the label in the callback.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Add timer at 60 frames a second
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:1.0/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];  
}

-(void) targetMethod: NSTimer * theTimer {
... update label
}
```

Comment: So I have to set a timer that updates the label at 60fps? Sounds like it would work, but isn't that rather unnecessary to have a task running like that all the time? 

Will use it in the meanwhile though - lets see if someone else has got something to say =)

Comment: If you want a real-time update then you don't have many choices?! If you just want a static value every time you go to a stats page however then add the a value to the NSUserDefaults and update it each time the user starts / ends a game.

Comment: I get it - thank you very much for your effort; seems to work like a charm =)